# Combination of lme/lmer with clmm2 when running mediation

Tags: r, ordinal-data, mediation, mixed-model

I was wondering whether it is possible to combine a cumulative link mixed model (clmm2) with the linear mixed model (lme4/nlme) when running a mediation (package mediation). I have been working with linear mixed models and mediation for a while, however now I am working with an ordinal variable (A) and two continuous variables (B, C). ID is the random variable for the same patients. My ordinal variable (A) has 4 levels.

Here comes the formulas that I have prepared:

```
outcome <- clmm2(A ~ B + C + (1|ID), data=test, Hess=TRUE, nAGQ=10)
mediator <- lmer(B ~ C + (1|ID), data=test)
total <- mediate(mediator, outcome, treat = "C", mediator = "B", sims=10000)
```

Although I get the models from the two first formulas, when I run the mediation command I get the following error:

```
Error in formula.default(object, env = baseenv()) : invalid formula
```

Any help is welcome..

Kostas